# How to solve "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '[Method Name]' is undefined"

Tags: undefined

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebClient._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var count = 0;
        function Start()
        {
            setInterval("ReadNotification()", 1000);
        }
        function ReadNotification()
        {
            alert(++count);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="return Start();">
</body>
</html>
```

I just run this code and received a classic error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Start' is undefined
```

I dont't know why, because I really defined this method.
How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the script tag for jquery is not closig properly unless you put a  tag to close it, which renders those objects not readable, which gives you the error.

Code below, hope this helps.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebClient._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        var count = 0;
        function Start()
        {
            setInterval("ReadNotification()", 5000);
        };
        function ReadNotification()
        {
            alert(++count);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="return Start();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really works fine!
But why? I remembered that people tell me that the script should close with '/>'. Not clear in my mind......

Comment: You got it Jeffrey, I'm not so sure, why this is the case but when you have runat=server, it screws up the opening/closing brackets.  But if you explicitly set them, it renders correctly.