# jquery createdialog undefined error

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to show images in a dialog box. While running the code I am getting an error        `id is undefined and  Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'createdialog' is undefined`

```
 $(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal:true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: "auto"
    });

    var id= $(this).attr('@Model.Id')
    $(function createdialog(id)
        {         

        $("#dialog").html("<img src='" + $(this).next().find('id').attr("src") + "' width='250' +  height='300'>");
        $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {
               modal:"true",
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            });
        if ($("#dialog").dialog("isOpen") == false) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where are you calling `createdialog`?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle and from where $(this).attr('@Model.Id') this is coming?

Comment: It works fine for me.. i.e no createdialog is undefined error.

Comment: It could be something small. check this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303850/how-to-solve-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-method-name-is-undefined

Comment: why are you trying to wrap `function createdialog(id)` in `$()`?